# Database Update periodically in an MVC3 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working in a web project using ASP.NET MVC3 and entity for database access.

I need to update database everyday automatically. To be more specific I need to check the database to see if the records are older than one month or more and set their status as old (there is a status and date created field in the table).

How can I do that?

Comment: Easiest way is through a scheuled task on the server. SQL server has one of it's own or you could execute a sql script from the one in the OS.

Comment: thanks Tony. But, I have to do it programmatically. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I gave you a programatic solution. The non programatic solution would be you manually deleting the records from the database! I'm sure I can help seeing as I think of a dozen ways this could be done, can't choose one without more info. What are you "allowed" to use to do it, and maybe a bit of why you are so constrained.

Comment: @Muctadir If the website is all you can do, i would then write a stored proc and invoke this on any request that is valid. If there is a LOT of data, AND provided you're on MS Sql, i would enable SQL broker and run the stored proc in a detached way (e.g. so that your website responses are not dependant on the completion of the stored proc).

Answer (score 1):

If you must do it through .net code and cannot create a SQL server task, then you could create a executable that gets kicked off by a windows scheduled task.  Or your executable could be a windows services that uses a timer.  I don't understand why you would want to put that logic in a website.

Comment: Me neither. Not using SQl Scheduler I can see, but after that I'm stumped as to why you'd even try not to do it properly.

Comment: @Ryand, there are environments where website is all that you got.